# How to add SSH known host to known host file on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, known-hosts

The `known_hosts` file does not look trivial. On Windows I see it contains hostname, ip address and some RSA key.

On linux I see it contains several keys separated by bar.

Who manages this file on Windows? How to add some host as "known" to this file on Windows?

Can Putty do this? If Putty has some host as known, can I copy this host record from Putty database to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` on Windows?

Comment: Why do you want to have `known_hosts` on Windows?

Comment: For OpenSSH, ~/.ssh/known_hosts can contain hashed host names (this is controlled by the HashKnownHosts configuration directive). Hashed host names start with a `|` character. Other SSH clients may work differently.

Answer (score 4):

PuTTY stores the known hosts in the Windows Registry. In the FAQ, [they offer a Python script](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-hostkeys) to convert an existing `known_hosts` file to a Windows .REG file, but adding to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` won't add to the hosts that PuTTY trusts.

You can also add hosts individually by connecting via PuTTY and clicking Yes on the PuTTY Security Alert. To do this, either open the PuTTY GUI and fill out the required fields to connect, or invoke it from the command line: `putty.exe username@hostname port`

Comment: to add to this you could also use plink: `plink.exe user@hostname -P 22 -ssh -i /path/to/private/key`

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 Pro, you can add Open SSH Client from Settings -> Apps -> Optional features. This gets you both `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-keyscan`.

In my case, I had to first run `ssh-keygen` to get me the key pair in `%HOMEPATH%\.ssh`. I then uploaded the public key file to the host I want to connect to as per their instructions.

Then in a command prompt in my .ssh directory, I ran `ssh-keyscan [host] > known_hosts`.

(I could then connect automagically from a simple python script using `paramiko`.)